# Construct a bijection $F(C, A \times B)\to F(C ,A) \times F(C, B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A, B, C$ be sets. Construct a bijective function $F(C, A \times B)\to F(C ,A) \times F(C, B)$.

Here, $F(C, A \times B)$ is the set of functions $f: C \to A \times B$.

Could someone show me the way how to do this? What questions should I ask myself?

I understand that $F(C, A \times B)$ is also denoted as $(A\times B)^C$ and that $F(C ,A) \times F(C, B)$ is also denoted as $A^C \times B^C$, so that indeed I need to construct a bijective function $(A\times B)^C \to A^C \times B^C$.

But how to do this?

Comment: Are there any additional relations among these sets?

Comment: No, this is all the information available.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** What relation is there between a function $f: C \to A \times B$ and a pair of functions $f_A: C \to A$ and $f_B: C \to B$?

---

**In arduous detail, as the hint seems insufficient:**

We want to construct a bijection $\Psi: (A\times B)^C \to A^C \times B^C$. That is to say, to each function $f:C \to A \times B$, we want to associate a pair $(g,h)$ such that:

$$g: C \to A\quad \text{and}\quad h:C \to B$$

Let us see what happens, for a given $c \in C$. We only have access to $f(c)$, and we know that $f(c) = (a,b)$ for some $a\in A,b\in B$.

From $f$, and in particular, from $f(c)$ (do you see why it suffices to consider one $c$ at a time), we need to cook up new functions $g: C \to A$ and $h: C \to B$, respectively $g(c)$ and $h(c)$.

The obvious choice is $g(c) = a, h(c) = b$, where $f(c) = (a,b)$. We see that the pair $(g,h)$ is uniquely determined by $f$ (for it is at each $c \in C$), and conversely, that we can recover $f$ as $f(c) = (g(c),h(c))$. So this process determines $\Psi: (A\times B)^C \to A^C \times B^C$, and shows it to be a bijection.

Comment: could I say: 
Let f∈F(C,A X B) and let (g)∈F(C,A)XF(C,B). 
Define Ψ: F(C,A×B)→F(C,A)×F(C,B) with Ψ(f)(a,b)=f(a)(b). 
And say that this is a bijective function because it has an inverse 
Φ: F(C,A)×F(C,B)→F(C,A×B) with   Φ(g)(a)(b)=g(a,b) ?

Comment: the relation is that the functions f and the pair of functions both map to the set A and B?

Comment: You seem to be confusing the domain and codomain of a function (or at least, I can't make sense of $\Psi(f)(a,b) = f(a)(b)$). $f: C \to A \times B$ takes inputs from $C$, and outputs ordered pairs $(a,b) \in A \times B$.

Comment: Yes I see it now to. So should it be:  Define Ψ: F(C,A×B)→F(C,A)×F(C,B) with Ψ(f)(c)=f(a,b). And say that this is a bijective function because it has an inverse Φ: F(C,A)×F(C,B)→F(C,A×B) with Φ(g)(a,b)(c)=g(a,b)?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is all very logic and good to understand, but is this answer still a hint, or an answer? What I mean is: are f,g and h the constructed bijective function(s) and has your answer proven this as well?

Comment: The last paragraph remains to be fully formalised ($\Psi$ has to be rigorously defined, then shown to be both injective and surjective), but otherwise the proof is complete. I'll leave the rest to you as a proof-writing exercise. Spelling it out has no additional educational value.

Comment: One last advice: If you would like feedback on your proposed proof, just post a new question, link to this one, and tag it [tag:proof-verification]. That way, you'll get the attention of all MSE users instead of just me. Good luck :).