# Proving that a function $F(C,A×B)→F(C,A)×F(C,B)$ is a bijection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551530/construct-a-bijection-fc-a-times-b-to-fc-a-times-fc-b) earlier, and wanted to check if this proof is good.

Chose a function $f∈F(C,A×B)$ and $c∈C$ arbitrary. We know $f(c)∈A×B.$ Define $g:C→A$ by $g(c)=a$ for all $c∈C$ and define $h:C→B$ by $h(c)=b$ for all $c∈C.$ We now know that $f(c)=(a,b)$ for some $a∈A,$ $b∈B.$

Define $Ψ: F(C,A×B) → F(C,A) × F(C,B)$ by $Ψ(f)=(g,h)$ for all $f∈F(C,A×B).$

We show that $Ψ$ is bijective by showing it is injective and surjective. 
Let $f,(g,h)∈F(C,A×B)$. If $Ψ(f)=Ψ(g,h)$ then $f=(g,h).$ Thus $Ψ$ is injective.

Now let $(g,h)∈F(C,A)×F(C,B).$ For every $a∈A$ and $b∈B$ there exist $c∈C$ such that $g(c)=a$ and $f(c)=b$. So $Ψ(g,h)=(a,b)$ and $Ψ$ is surjective.

Thus $Ψ$ is bijective.

Comment: You should have posted this as an answer to your own question, rather than a separate question.

Comment: Do you mean that my proof in this post is correct?

Comment: Did I say that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this site and how to post. I'm sorry if I failed. Could you check if my prove is correct?

Comment: It's probably worth noting somewhere that $A$,$B$, and $C$ are sets and $F(A,B)$ is the set of functions from $A$ to $B$. My first instinct was to read this as a statement in category theory, where the bijection in question is wired into the definition of products.

Comment: There is a link to the question. This post is to check if my prove is correct

Comment: @AsafKaragila I plainly disagree that such *should* have been done. Sure, it's a possibility, but there's nothing wrong with this practice.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: I have no issue *in general* with proof verification questions. However posting the question just a few hours ago, and then posting another one for a solution verification seems silly. Especially since often one can fully give an answer using comments to these questions (rarely the proof is so badly written that one *truly needs* the full space of an answer to write a critique). Posting this as a separate question *in this case* seems plainly irrational to me.

Comment: does nobody like my proof?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Blame it on me, then. I [suggested](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551530/construct-a-bijection-fc-a-times-b-to-fc-a-times-fc-b/551540#comment1174623_551540) the OP post this. (And by the looks of it, I don't think it's a bad suggestion.)

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Will do. Let me grab my voodoo kit and make a little doll in the shape of you. You might feel very hot in the next few hours, as I leave the doll on the stove over night. :-)

Comment: a 'yes' will do

Comment: @logicjohnnny No offence, but you made mistakes on all three important parts: the definition of $\Phi$, its injectivity, and its surjectivity. However I don't have time now to elaborate on it, so you'll have to hope someone else comes along, or you'll have to be patient (I'll keep an eye on this question, and answer it if nobody else does).